# Why is my SQLite query returning the system date as 1970-01-01?

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I'm writing a Java desktop application. This code used to work fine with my mock database. Now it is returning `1970-01-01` as system date.I'm using eclipse. Please help.

```
JButton btnCheckAvailability = new JButton("Check Availability");
            btnCheckAvailability.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int count=0;
                    String q="Select * from IssueLog where Book_id= ?";
                    try{
                    PreparedStatement p=con.prepareStatement(q);
                    p.setString(1,bid);
                    ResultSet rst=p.executeQuery();

                        while(rst.next()){
                            count++;

                        String q2 ="select date('now')";

                            PreparedStatement pst5 = con.prepareStatement(q2);
                            ResultSet rs55 = pst5.executeQuery();
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rs55.getDate(1));  
                            if((rs55.getDate(1)).before(rst.getDate("Due_Date"))){
                                String qw="Select Name from Members where Id_no=?";
                                PreparedStatement pst0=con.prepareStatement(qw);
                                pst0.setString(1, rst.getString("id_no"));
                                ResultSet r = pst0.executeQuery();
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"It is currently with "+r.getString("Name")+"\nCome back after "+rst.getString("Due_Date"));
                                pst5.close();
                                pst0.close();
                                rs55.close();
                                r.close();
                            }
                            else
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Available");


                            }

                    rst.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(count!=1)
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Available");

                }

            });
```

Comment: this is the date from which time is calculated. you would get it if constructing date object with 0 miliseconds

Comment: Different databases have different idioms for using dates and times. Some databases may use `date('now')`, others `now()`, and others `current_date` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how this happened. 
But here's what worked.

```
                        String q2 ="select date('now')";

                        PreparedStatement pst5 = con.prepareStatement(q2);
                        ResultSet rs55 = pst5.executeQuery();
                        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rs55.getString(1));    

                        if(rs55.getString(1).compareTo(rst.getString("Due_Date"))>0){
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `select NOW()` instead of `select date('now')`. I guess you get null in your query and then when you call rs55.getDate(1) you get a Date object that is constructed as 0 milliseconds from epoch which is 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

Comment: That gives an error. Missing databse or no such column.

Comment: why don't you get that Date as new Date(). I don't see the reason to use query.